# Why am I seeing this ad?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

When I navigate to questions tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), I'm seeing the following advertisement.

[image]

The first link - 'A link' - points to `http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/clk?id=4471276698&iu=/248424177/stackoverflow.com/tag-sponsorship`

And the second link - 'To the job' - points to `http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/clkid=4471276698&iu=/248424177/stackoverflow.com/tag-sponsorship`

What is this? Why is this ad showing? How can I avoid/remove/close this annoying ad?

It appears to be only showing for the c# tab.

Comment: I guess you're just _un-lucky_.

Comment: Fairly sure that's placeholder bumph that's not meant to be showing... :p

Comment: Judging by the text in the picture, looks like the ad server is down. The link text also looks very placeholderish and just link to stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com/jobs - not to a specific listing/site.

Comment: Which browser/version are you using? I've a feeling why you're seeing that ad. Is this just for that tag though?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why are you not seeing it? It is showing in my browser.

Comment: @mega6382 Because, I'm not on "IE", *lol!* which I suspect is what the OP's using (and you also maybe). That, or they haven't a plugin to block those.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I'm using Chrome `[version : 61.0.3163.100]`

Comment: With addblocker enabled it is hidden for me. Just shows up after disabling it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm seeing it on chrome. You're probably not seeing it because you've got reduced ads. It showed immediately for me in incognito mode

Comment: ^ OK guys (for the above pings). That could be it (for me).

Comment: I'm getting the same in `IE` also

Comment: A screenshot in jpeg is disturbing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

good thing that works! It's due to some work I'm doing. I'll disable it and it shouldn't appear anymore.

---

Just to provide more context. I'm working on a small tool to allow our sales folks to create such tag sponsorship ads automatically. I used it to create that "test" sponsorship some time ago and set the starting date for it to the far off "31st of October", with the goal of disabling it when it's finished. Things dragged on unfortunately.

Comment: Could have been worse. Some of my debugging messages and placeholder images are much more NSFW.

Comment: Well, it seems to have gone away now.

Comment: @mega6382 yes, there's a small delay between when we make a change and when it's reflected in "serving"

Comment: @Matt and this is why we don't do that!

Comment: @Matt feel free to share ... oh wait ...